# Вернуть биты из строки

Tags: java, android, криптография

Кодирую строку, получаю байты, конвертирую в строку и сохраняю  при помощи `SharedPreferences`. В дальнейшем декодировать строку не получится, как снова получить массив байтов?

```
private void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String s = "ab";
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(128);
    final SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
    //SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("bar12345Bar12345".getBytes(),"AES");
    time.setText(String.valueOf(key));
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
    final byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String s=new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    for (byte b : bytes)
        kkk+=(char) b;

    //time.setText(s);
    byte[] byteArray = kkk.getBytes();

    //  String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Cipher decript = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    decript.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] decriptedBytes = decript.doFinal(bytes);
    for (byte b : decriptedBytes)
        kk+=(char) b;

    time.setText(kk);

    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sPref = getSharedPreferences("save",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putString(SAVED_L,  s);
            ed.commit();
            Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, kk+String.valueOf(key),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете неправильный подход, строки не предназначены для хранения произвольного набора байт. Попробуйте зашифрованные байты кодировать в base64. При расшифровке декодируйте base64 строку в байты, и дальше расшифруйте их, как обычно.

Comment: String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,4); для чего нужен второй параметр

Comment: Там уже есть `java.util.Base64`, без всяких параметров: `String x = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `Base64` самый идеологически верный, но не единственный.

Можете использовать `Charsets.ISO_8859_1` вместо `UTF-8` для преобразования произвольного набора байтов в строку и обратно.

Но стоить помнить, что эта строка не для отображения в UI или пересылки в текстовом виде!